# Laravel 9 - Vite is not bundling my images even if I declared the entry point

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-vite

I am using Laravel 9.27.0

I am trying to reference an image directly on my master.blade.php located on resources/views. This image is being used as the favicon for the site I am working on. According to the documentation, I should be able to reference this image with Vite by adding the following to my app.js

```
import.meta.glob([
  '../images/**'
]);
```

And I should be referencing the image in my blade using this code.

```
{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/favicon.png') }}
```

However I kept getting `Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/images/favicon.png.`

Am I misunderstanding this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: and the image is located in `resources/images/` ?

Comment: yes, I made sure of that.

Comment: Same problem here. Only on specific images in png.

Answer (score 6):

You have to follow this:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#working-with-blade-and-routes,

In **resources/js/app.js** you have to add

```
import.meta.glob([ '../images/**', ]);
```

and also in your **config/app.php** have facade alias defined:

```
'Vite' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite::class,
```

then you can use

```
<img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/photo.jpg') }}" >
```

Comment: then use 

src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/photo.jpg') }}"

Comment: Run composer update as well if Vite::asset not available in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite::class

Answer (score 0):

You could try also run command:

```
npm run build
```

That also will reload everything in Vite config.

Comment: I have been doing this all the time but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502963/larave-vite-vite-manifest-missing-odd-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502963/larave-vite-vite-manifest-missing-odd-files#answer-73503046)

Need to add this in `vite.config.js`:

```
build: {
    assetsInlineLimit: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

It was about read permissions on the images folder, as the web server was not permitted to access and read it.