# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: logo.png

Tags: laravel, vite

So I'm encountering this issue and I can't solve it so I thought post it here.

I found similar issues but those are about `.css` files and I'm dealing with images.

1. [Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unable-to-locate-file-in-vite-manifest-resourcescssappcss)
2. [Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/unable-to-locate-file-in-vite-manifest-resourcescssappcss-2)
3. [Larave & Vite - Vite manifest missing odd files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502963/larave-vite-vite-manifest-missing-odd-files)

Here's my problem.

I ran `npm run build` and it was successful, the files are inside `public/build/assets/` folder and the `manifest.json`  is inside the `public/build/` but I'm getting "**Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: logo.png.**

```
- public
  - build
    - assets
      - logo-7b466471.png
    - resources
      - index.html
    - manifest.json
```

The `manifest.json` has:

```
"resources/images/logo.png": {
  "file": "assets/logo-7b466471.png",
  "src": "resources/images/logo.png"
},
```

Here's how I use the image inside my blade.php file:

```
<img src="{{ Vite::asset('logo.png') }}">
```

In my `app.js` I have this at the very top:

```
import.meta.glob(["../images/**", "../fonts/**"]);
```

I have tried the solutions mention in the post.

EDIT:

I'm using the latest Laravel Framework: `"laravel/framework": "^10.20.0"`

My `package.json`:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.3",
"laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
"vite": "^4.4.9",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 9 - Vite is not bundling my images even if I declared the entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582355/laravel-9-vite-is-not-bundling-my-images-even-if-i-declared-the-entry-point)

Comment: Your image file location is ``resources/images/logo.png`` but you're referencing as only ``Vite::asset('logo.png')`` !!!

Comment: My bad. Anyways I've solved the issue as provided in the answer below.

Comment: lol ! Just because I used exclamation mark, it means I am shouting? Salute to you buddy!

Comment: Salute to you too, buddy.

Comment: and the way you solved, it's totally wrong. Think of like this: How would you reference a file residing in the following location: ``resources/clients/file.png``? It'll always point to ``resources/images/resources/clients/file.png`` since you modified the path. So you should not go with the solution you added.

Comment: Just declare another `Vite` macro. Easy as that. Read the docs and you'll find out.

EDIT: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#blade-processing-static-assets

Comment: I am aware of that, that's just an another (a little longer) way of doing same but you have to repeat the process again when you can simply go with the simple solution, anyways your choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like no one has encountered this before.

I've solved it by doing the following:

1. Make sure you're using Node 18.17 or higher.
2. If you already run `npm install` delete the node_modules folder.
3. Run `npm install` again.
4. Run `npm run build`.
5. In your `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` add this line of code in the `boot` method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite;

public function boot(): void
{
    Vite::macro('image', fn (string $asset) => $this->asset("resources/images/{$asset}"));
}
```

6. In your blade file use the the `Vite` macro like this:

```
<img src="{{ Vite::image('logo.png') }}" />
```

7. Lastly, in your `vite.config.js` add this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 3072, // 3MB
    assetsInlineLimit: 0,
  },
  plugins: [
    // ...
  ],
});
```

Comment: Kindly, do not add comment(s) to your solution. That's not how we do on StackOverFlow.

Comment: and the way you solved, it's totally wrong. Think of like this: How would you reference a file residing in the following location: resources/clients/file.png? It'll always point to resources/images/resources/clients/file.png since you modified the path. So you should not go with the solution you added. – OMi Shah

There's nothing wrong with it as we can declare another macro.

Comment: Carry on buddy. You seem totally off the track.